# How to get rid of warning 'Type ... is not assignable to type' typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript

This is probably a stupid question, but I wanna know how I can get rid of warning in **currentNum** variable. The warning is = '**Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'StrType'**'. The **currentNum** variable is the string witch exist in the StrType type. But it shows me a warning

```
type StrType = 'one' | 'two' | 'three'

const initialNum = 'one1'

const currentNum: StrType = initialNum.slice(0, initialNum.length - 1)
```

Answer (score 3):

The only practical typesafe way to ensure you're getting string of `StrType` type is to narrow the type of `String.prototype.slice` result from `string` to your type. You may use any of [type narrowing](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html) technics. Also you may use [custom guard](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#using-type-predicates) or [assertion functions](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-7.html#assertion-functions).

With type guard:

```ts
type StrType = 'one' | 'two' | 'three'

const initialNum = 'one1'

function isStrType(str: string): str is StrType {
  return ['one', 'two', 'three'].includes(str)
}

const maybeStrType = initialNum.slice(0, initialNum.length - 1)

if (isStrType(maybeStrType)) {
  const currentNum: StrType = maybeStrType; // no error
}
```

[playground link](https://tsplay.dev/m3Abkw)

---

Though if you want to ensure it in compile time you have to 'lift' your `slice` function and indexes on type-level. [Peano numbers](https://mjj.io/2021/03/29/type-level-programming-in-typescript/) is a good example of how you can represent natural number's arithmetic on type-level.

First we have to define our type-level numbers:

```ts
type Zero = "zero" // base case

type Succ<N> = { n: N } // inductive step
```

That's enough to represent 0 and all natural numbers;

```ts
type One = Succ<Zero>
type Two = Succ<One>
type Three = Succ<Two>
type Four = Succ<Three>
type Five = Succ<Four>
type Six = Succ<Five>
type Seven = Succ<Six>
type Eight = Succ<Seven>
type Nine = Succ<Eight>
type Ten = Succ<Nine>

type Decrement<N> = N extends Succ<infer R> ? R : Zero

type Num = Zero | One | Two | Three | Four | Five | Six | Seven | Eight | Nine | Ten

// helper function to convert Num to number
function fromNum(n: Num, acc: number = 0): number {
    return (n === "zero") ? acc : fromNum(n.n, acc + 1);
}

// --- some Num constants
const zero: Zero = "zero"
const one: One = { n: zero }
const two: Two = { n: { ...one } }
const three: Three = { n: { ...two } }
const four: Four = { n: { ...three } }
const five: Five = { n: { ...four } }
```

Then we have to define `Slice` type. We're given string `S`, starting index `From` and finishig index `To`. Also we have accumulator string `R`. At the start we assign it to empty string `''`.

On each step we split `S` into `First` character and the `Rest` of the string.

- If `From` is not `Zero` yet we discard first character, decrease both `From` and `To` indexes and call `Slice` with decreased indexes and `Rest` string. Accumulator stays untouched.
- If `From` is `Zero` and `To` is not `Zero` yet we decrease `To` add `First` character to the end of the accumulator `R` and call `Slice` with `Rest` of the string, decreased `To` index and concatenated accumulator.
- If `From` is `Zero` and `To` is `Zero` we have reached the final step of our slice process and return accumulated string `R`.

```ts
type Slice<S extends string, From extends Num, To extends Num, R extends string = ''> = S extends `${infer First}${infer Rest}`
    ? From extends Zero
        ? To extends Zero
            ? R
            : Slice<Rest, Zero, Decrement<To>, `${R}${First}`>
        : Slice<Rest, Decrement<From>, Decrement<To>, R> 
    : R
```

[playground link](https://tsplay.dev/w26Bjw)

I'd strongly recommend against using this in production though.

Answer (score 0):

You can say that the result of slice will always be of type `StrType` using [Type Assertions](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#type-assertions)

```js
const currentNum = initialNum.slice(0, initialNum.length - 1) as StrType;
```

Comment: Unfortunatly, this solution breaks the idea of the TypeScript - type check. Simply check this code: 
```const currentNum: StrType = initialNum.slice(0, initialNum.length - 2) as StrType;```

Comment: Thanks man. It`s solved my problem. As far as I'm understand, if the result 
will not be one of types, it  will not show the error?

Comment: You're basically telling the TS compiler that the result of ````initialNum.slice```` will always be of type ````StrType````. Type assertions are removed by the compiler and won’t affect the runtime behavior of your code